# Why do my burgers end up round?

Tags: meat, hamburgers, ground-beef

When I broil or grill my burgers, I end up with burgers that are round in the middle.

I grind my own beef blend and form my patties the same every time. When I cook my burgers in a pan I don't get the rounded burgers.

What makes the burgers rounded and smaller when broiling/grilling, but not with pan cooking?

Comment: I know this is a bit obvious, but when you fry them, do you squish them with the skillet at all as they're cooking?

Comment: FWIW: loose-packed burgers made with course-ground beef don't suffer from this problem - I suspect they're better able to shrink evenly as the fat renders out, where tightly-packed patties find the edge shrinking faster than the center.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure what causes the bowing to be more pronounced from one cooking method versus another, but **the solution is to put a thumbprint indentation in the middle,** creating a slight "donutted" shape.   This will help to ensure you get the "patty" shape you want.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is probably the level of heat being applied to the burgers. Pan frying is only heating one side and probably isn't as intense as the broil/grill method.

I always use a [patty press](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001C68OIG) when I make my burgers since it compacts them really well and helps them to be less round.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the same effect as frying Baloney (yeah, think back to college) - if you're using thin patties put little slits in three places and the bubbling effect will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Making an indentation works, but I prefer to poke a hole all the way through with my pinky finger. The hole disappears while cooking.

Answer (score 0):

On top of using a patty press as [Bryant](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/143/why-do-my-burgers-end-up-round/160#160) suggested, freezing the patties first helps them hold their shape until they cooked enough to be self-supporting.